# how to design search for multiple fields in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

[Form]: ![Form to be Considered][Form]

[Form]:[image: Access Form]

I have these form from Access. Here, I am developing search application on asp.net. I have 2 heavy databases with same data structure in which one database include approx 12000 fields and another has approx. 9000 records. I want to do search records with any criteria say,

Dealer Number = 3123 and DLicenceNo = 3242314

Here, I am assuming that if user provides a field text, that only considered to be search, and others to be ignored.

Is there anyway to build query for this rather using long if clauses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably needs some tweaking but, start by naming all your textbox controls your column names in your database

```
var conditionals = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach(Control c in Page.Controls)
{
    if (c is TextBox)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(c.Text))
            conditionals.Add(c.Id, c.Text);
    }
}
```

From there you could be VERY careful to build a query that only has the right where clauses based on your conditionals dictionary. Ideally you can make sure it's parameterized some how to avoid all worries of SQL Injection.

Comment: your answer is practical then other answers that I don't need to work out for 39 fields. Thanks...

Comment: I found one limitation for labelling label fields. Say, in database have one named column [Mon/Year], how can I label this to my Label?

Comment: That's kind of ugly - ideally you could rename your database column to something that could work better. Alternatively you could add a special case in your query builder to say something like if ID = "monyear" then column = "[Mon/Year]". So your control has an ID that is valid, and it gets converted. But once you go down that path it starts to get a bit ugly imo.

Comment: I know that's ugly, but this was structured by someone... Anyways, I found this is the best approach, but I solved it using queue, and its working really nice..

Answer (score 1):

I use stored procedures, passing parameters default values, like this:

```
select field1,field2,... from table1 where 
(dealer_number= @dealer_number or @dealer_number='0')
and (d_licence_no=@d_licence_no or @d_licence_no='0')
```

If you're not using some parameter for this search, just send its default value, and that criteria will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Sql Case` statement ,they are easy to manage ,
query can be like

```
declare @SearchItem varchar(50);
declare @SearchValue int;

SELECT column1, column2
FROM table
WHERE
@SearchValue = 
  CASE @SearchItem 
      WHEN 'Dealer Number' THEN ''
      WHEN 'DLicenceNo ' THEN ''

  END
```

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

use the stored procedure with all search criterias as your sp arguments and pass it null when you doesn't want to apply any condition. sp will be as

```
Create procedure usp_search
(
   @dealerNumber int=null,
    @licenseNumber int=null
)
as 
select * from table where
dealerNumber= isnull(@dealerNumber,dealerNumber)
and licenseNumber = isnull(@licenseNumber ,licenseNumber )
```